# How to rewrite part of URL in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this URL:

```
example.com/news/article/254
```

How to make a PHP script to process this URL (`example.com/blog/article/254`) as `example.com/news/article/254`,
and `example.com/blog` as `example.com/news`, etc.

Comment: So, I don't see any current code or even the actual php URL to rewrite? You didn't provide really enough clear information to help.

Comment: I need code for .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work if you add it to your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^blog/article/(.+?)\/?$ /news/article/$1 [R=301, L]
</IfModule>
```

If you don't want to tell robots etc. that you have permanently redirected then take out the "R=301, " above.

Comment: i've tested the code and works, however, placement in your .htaccess file could be an issue or perhaps you don't need the IfModule test.  Can you post or send me your .htaccess file?